# bash prevent copy of containing folders

Tags: bash

The following script loops through a file list and makes copies of the files to a folder "src" located in the same folder as the script.

one of the files / folders list is the folder containing the script.

How can I prevent it recursively copying the src folder into itself:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=files.txt
if [ -d src ]; then
    mkdir -p src
fi
rm -rf src/*
while read FILE; do
    DIR="src$(dirname $FILE)"
    NAME=$(basename $FILE) 
    if [ ! -d "$DIR" ]; then
        echo "Create $DIR"
        mkdir -p $DIR
    fi

    if [ -d "$FILE" ]; then
        echo Copying "FOLDER $FILE > $DIR/$NAME"
        cp -rp "$FILE" "$DIR/$NAME"
    elif [ -f "$FILE" ]; then
        echo Copying "FILE $FILE > $DIR/$NAME"
        cp -p "$FILE" "$DIR/$NAME"
    fi
done <$FILES
```

Hope that's clear, sounds a bit confusing, but I'm not sure how else to phrase it !

## EDIT

My ultimate goal is actually to collect specific files and folders from the disk into the src folder and then to push these source files to a git repo.

Comment: why can't you remove src folder from `files.txt` file

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your script as it stands. First, the fix to it that you requested, without changing any of the other issues:

Add a check to see if `$FILE` is equivalent to `$PWD/src`. If it is, just `continue` the loop, as in

```
# avoid recursively copying src into itself
if [ "$FILE" == "$PWD/src" ];
then
    continue
fi
```

However, this assumes that the paths in `files.txt` are absolute.
If the paths are relative, they must be visible under their listed names in order for `dirname`, `basename`, and `cp` to work, which means they are paths relative to the current working directory, and we can simplify the check to `"$FILE" == "src"`

If you have denormalized paths like `src/../src`, then the check won't work.
My favorite way of handling this on Linuxes with GNU utilities is to use `readlink -f` to canonicalize full paths, as in

```
if [ "$(readlink -f "$FILE")" == "$(readlink -f "$PWD/src")" ];
then
    continue
fi
```

You may be wondering why I use `readlink` on the `$PWD`, but it makes sense if you assume that one of the directories you traversed in order to reach the current directory is a symlink. The results of canonicalizing the path of `$FILE` would mismatch with the `$PWD` erroneously in that case.

If you are on a system with BSD utilities, like an OSX machine, then `readlink` won't support the `-f` option, and things start getting trickier.
Remember, the case we're trying to handle is a path in `files.txt` which contains a symlink, but actually refers to `src`. Something like `../mysymlink/src`, in which `mysymlink` actually points to the current directory.

The easiest way to do this unambiguously that I know of is to inspect the inode number of `src` and check if it matches the file when following symlinks:

```
# fetch the inode number for src, following symlinks
src_inode_num="$(stat -L --format=%i src)"
# fetch the inode number for FILE, following symlinks
file_inode_num="$(stat -L --format=%i "$FILE")"
# compare inode numbers to see if they are the same directory
if [ "$file_inode_num" == "$src_inode_num" ];
then
    continue
fi
```

I recommend looking at the `stat` manpage, but in short `-L` means that `stat` follows symlinks without giving their `stat` information, and `--format=%i` tells stat to only print the inode number.

If you have a lot more information about `files.txt`, then other solutions may be available in which you can use `grep` or other tools to remove instances of `src` before even processing the file.

---

Now that all of that is taken care of, you should give consideration to other symlinks that may appear in your file list, since they will result in duplicates of the original files.

The simple solution is to do

```
if [ -L "$FILE" ];
then
    ...
    cp -P "$FILE" "$DIR/$NAME"
fi
```

Note that this will not prevent the `if [ -f` and `if [ -d` checks from succeeding -- symlinks will pass these as well, so be sure to skip them when `if [ -L` passes.

Of course, all of this is vulnerable to the same set of issues above for `src`, so you should really do much more work if you want to avoid duplicates when there are symlinks embedded in a path.
Again, you can use `readlink -f`, or, since you mean to copy things, you can traverse the path (repeated `dirname` works fine) looking for links, and recreating the ones you find with `cp -P`.

---

A few quibbles:

- No need to check `if [ -d src` at the beginning, since `mkdir -p src` is safe even if it exists. I find it easier to read without the `if` block, and a simple comment like `# ensure src exists`. Also, your current check is wrong -- it only creates `src` if it already exists.
- I much prefer `src/$(dirname "$FILE")` because it's clear that we are concatenating paths. In the shell `//` is equivalent to `/`, so there's no harm in this. If it bothers you, you can always `sed 's://:/:g'`, but that would ignore paths like `a\//b`, so I wouldn't bother.
- You use `"$DIR/$NAME"` in a bunch of places, so why not put it in a variable? Perhaps something semantic like "target".
- Put "Copying" inside the quotation marks for your `echo`s
- As with `src` at the beginning, no need to check existence before `mkdir -p src`.
- Be more vigilant about quoting strings. Things like `"$(basename "$FILE")"`
- `src/$(dirname "$FILE")/$(basename "$FILE")` is really just `src/"$FILE"`, so why not use that? i.e. `target="src/$FILE"`, in which case we can omit the call to `basename`
- Desperately needs comments. If you elided these for SO, I think it's better not to, since they clarify to all readers -- including SO readers.

The question I end up with at the end of all of this though is "What do you want to do?"
You've given us a script which does something, and it's easy enough to patch more logic onto it to do exactly what you want, but perhaps you should edit the question to share your actual goal with us.
Perhaps there's a good use of `tar` here, using `files.txt` as a file table input, or perhaps this is really all solveable with a clever `rsync` command.
I don't want to waste time speculating based on the script contents, but my first instinct upon seeing this problem was that you want to create a backup -- of course, in that case, a directory named `src` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Wonderfully detailed answer and +1 for tech support. Good luck to all

Comment: Thanks so much for helping, as you asked, my ultimate goal is to copy only specific files and folders from the current volume to the src folder, which I will then use to push the files to a git repo.